# Use Cutesoft Javascript Obfuscator Online

Tags: javascript, html, web, obfuscation, offline

I don't have a stable Internet Connection at home and I am wondering how I can use `CuteSoft Javascript obfuscator` **OFFLINE**.

This is the link of the obfuscator: http://javascriptobfuscator.com/

Can someone help me???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ask them for their source code, but otherwise you can't.  It uses a ASP.NET script to perform the obfiscuation.

If you need one offline, write one.  Here's a simple obfuscator.

```
function obs(src){
    var str = '', i;
    for (i=0; i<src.length; i++) {
        str += "\\x" + src.charCodeAt(i).toString(16);
    }
    var e = "\\x" + "e".charCodeAt(0).toString(16)
    + "\\x" + "v".charCodeAt(0).toString(16)
    + "\\x" + "a".charCodeAt(0).toString(16)
    + "\\x" + "l".charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
    return 'window["' + e + '"]("' + str + '");';
}
```

#### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MhufX/)

e.g.

```
alert('some text')
```

becomes

```
window["\x65\x76\x61\x6c"]("\x61\x6c\x65\x72\x74\x28\x27\x73\x6f\x6d\x65\x20\x74\x65\x78\x74\x27\x29");
```